# Azure AD Logout Url - Redirect not working

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I'm using Azure AD to authenticate users into a ColdFusion web application.  All works great, except when I log the user out I want to redirect them back to a page in my application.  The logout works correctly as far as clearing the cookies, etc, but the redirect is not happening.

I'm using the following format on my URL for logging out

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>/oauth2/logout?&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&post_logout_redirect_uri=https://myredirecturl
```

If I do not supply a valid URI, it gives me a error message stating that `'post_logout_redirect_uri' value must be a valid absolute Uri.`.  So I know it's seeing the URL parameter properly, but it is just NOT redirecting.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things to try:

- Try using a different browser. That could indicate a browser-specific JavaScript issue.
- Try URL encoding the URL that you're redirecting to.
- Make sure the URL you are redirecting to is in the same domain as your web app.

Also, I noticed your logout URL is a little funny: you have both a "?" followed by a "&" before your client_id query string parameter. I suggest you remove the "&" and have your URL look like `.../oauth2/logout?client_id=...&post_logout_redirect_uri=...`

Comment: I can't believe I made that mistake.  It was the extra & after the logout?.  Thank you so much!!!